# Using Git Desktop and USB stick for Version Control

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to use git and making USB stick as my private remote server(could move to another computer easily and work in a 3-4 people small group) for my code version control and backup. As I would like to have a fancy interface to show my readme and commit history list, so I am trying to use Git Desktop in Windows, but I found I can't achieve my goal like showing readme, push commits to USB stick. Is there any suggestion for me so that I could achieve?

Comment: Download a github-like self run server tool and run it from the usb?

Comment: Since remote repo has no working directory, you should clone the remote repo firstly, and then get the files from working directory in your local repo.

Answer (score 0):

On your machine you'd want to clone the repo to the USB stick, and then add it as a remote on every machine you work on.

What might be simpler is to put an 'authoritative' repo on a network share or something and again add it as a remote.

However, before you proceed, understand that both of these methods effectively turn your distributed version control system into a centralized one.